# AngularJS using ng-repeat. Binding Expression not working

Tags: .net, angularjs

I am not getting  the expected output, I am getting the binding expressions as it is instead of the names, AS shown Below

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
UK
 London
 Manchestor
 Bringham
US
 Dallas
 Austin
 San Antonio
India
 HYD
 BLR
 DLH
```

OUTPUT:

```
{{country.name}} 
  {{city.name}}
```

Here is my coding. Please let me know if I make any mistake.

JS File

```
/// <reference path="angular.min.js" />

var app = angular
                .module("myModule",[])
                .controller("myController", function ($scope)
                {
                    var countries = [
                        {
                            name: "UK",
                            cities: [
                                { name: "London" },
                                { name: "Manchestor" },
                                { name: "Bringham" },
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: "US",
                            cities: [
                                { name: "Dallas" },
                                { name: "Austin" },
                                { name: "San Antonio" },
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: "India",
                            cities: [
                                { name: "Hyd" },
                                { name: "BLR" },
                                { name: "DLH" },
                            ]
                        }
                    ];

                    $scope.countries = countries;
                });
```

HTML File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <script src="Script.js"></script>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body ng-app="myModule" style="font-family:Arial" >
    <div ng-Controller="myController">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="country in countries">
               {{country.name}}
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="city in country.cities">
                          {{city.name}}
                    </li>
                </ul>  
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

All are welcome to help me out.

Thanks in Advance !!!﻿

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: check this pen https://codepen.io/keephacking/pen/mmVbpL ,its working.

Answer (score 0):

Check the order of importing script in your page if your angular app is in the script.js you should import it after importing  angularjs ! in this order :

```
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's ok but move the import of the script.js to the body tag or after the angular import.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.js">
</script>
    <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body ng-app="myModule" style="font-family:Arial" >
    <div ng-Controller="myController">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="country in countries">
               {{country.name}}
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="city in country.cities">
                          {{city.name}}
                    </li>
                </ul>  
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 
  <script>
 var app = angular
                .module("myModule",[])
                .controller("myController", function ($scope)
                {
                    var countries = [
                        {
                            name: "UK",
                            cities: [
                                { name: "London" },
                                { name: "Manchestor" },
                                { name: "Bringham" },
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: "US",
                            cities: [
                                { name: "Dallas" },
                                { name: "Austin" },
                                { name: "San Antonio" },
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: "India",
                            cities: [
                                { name: "Hyd" },
                                { name: "BLR" },
                                { name: "DLH" },
                            ]
                        }
                    ];

                    $scope.countries = countries;
                });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and it works. Is the angular.min.js in the same folder? Most likely your having the issue due to the library not loading